# Why the uncertainty principle implies the vacuum fluctuations?

Tags: heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, vacuum

Why the [vacuum fluctuations](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_fluctuation#) (Especificly, the creation of especial particles from vacuum) are
direct consequence from Heisenberg's uncertainty principle?

I heard it from a Youtube video, but there's no explanation.

Comment: Prof. Arnold Neumaier has an article ["The Vacuum Fluctuation Myth"](https://www.physicsforums.com/insights/vacuum-fluctuation-myth/).

Comment: Please define what "the vacuum fluctuations" are here (there are several possible meanings) and why you think Heisenberg's uncertainty principle has something to do with them. We already have plenty of questions about vacuum fluctuations and the HUP, see e.g. https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/146003/50583, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/16851/50583, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/53802/50583